# Запуск функции из строки

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qpainter

Делаю маленькую детскую программу, где ребенок раскрашивает разные рисунки, так как рисунков много хотел чтобы был способ загрузки последнего рисунка, над которым работал ребенок.

Ничего умнее не придумал, как сохранить в файл название функции и потом пытаюсь запустить функцию прочитав название из файла, но запуска нужной функции не происходит, ошибку тоже не дает. Или может есть более хороший вариант как сделать save/load.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
import inspect
import sys
import GlForm

class PrApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, GlForm.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;" % '#FF0000')
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;" % '#FFFFFF')
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;" % '#000000')
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;" % '#008000')
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;" % '#FF69B4')
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;" % '#4169E1')
        self.label.hide()
        self.last_x, self.last_y = None, None
        self.pen_color = QtGui.QColor('#FFFFFF')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_pen_color('#FF0000'))
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_pen_color('#FFFFFF'))
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_pen_color('#000000'))
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_pen_color('#008000'))
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_pen_color('#FF69B4'))
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_pen_color('#4169E1'))
        self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.pushButton_10.clicked.connect(self.load)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.last_x is None:
            self.last_x = e.x()
            self.last_y = e.y()
            return

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.label.pixmap())
        p = painter.pen()
        p.setWidth(8)
        p.setColor(self.pen_color)
        painter.setPen(p)
        painter.drawLine(self.last_x, self.last_y, e.x(), e.y())
        painter.end()
        self.update()

        self.last_x = e.x()
        self.last_y = e.y()

   def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
       self.last_x = None
       self.last_y = None

   def set_pen_color(self, c):
       self.pen_color = QtGui.QColor(c)

   def start(self):
       self.label.show()
       self.pushButton_9.hide()
       self.pushButton_10.hide()
       self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 951, 621))
       self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("podimNew.jpg"))
       self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.chistxolst)
       self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.chistris1)
       self.pushButton_11.clicked.connect(self.var2)
       # Сохранить
       tf = 'data.csv'
       f = open(tf, 'w')
       text = inspect.stack()[0][3]
       f.write(text)
       f.close()

   def var2(self):
       self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 951, 621))
       self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("traktorNew.jpg"))
       self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.chistxolst)
       self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.chistris2)
       # Сохранить
       tf = 'data.csv'
       f = open(tf, 'w')
       text = inspect.stack()[0][3]
       f.write(text)
       f.close()

   def chistxolst(self):
       self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 951, 621))
       self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Xolst.jpg"))

   def chistris1(self):
       self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 951, 621))
       self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("podimNew.jpg"))

   def chistris2(self):
       self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 951, 621))
       self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("traktorNew.jpg"))

   def load(self):      #Читаю файл и пытаюсь запустить функцию
       tf = 'data.csv'
       f = open(tf)
       a = f.read()  
       f.close()
       m = PrApp()
       func = getattr(m, a)
       func()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PrApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**GlForm.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1280, 690)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1022, 20, 231, 28))
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 951, 621))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(255, 255, 255)")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1022, 60, 231, 28))
        self.pushButton_2.setText("")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1022, 110, 231, 28))
        self.pushButton_3.setText("")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1020, 150, 231, 28))
        self.pushButton_4.setText("")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1022, 190, 231, 28))
        self.pushButton_5.setText("")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1022, 230, 231, 28))
        self.pushButton_6.setText("")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1020, 330, 231, 28))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1020, 370, 231, 28))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 220, 111, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(482, 220, 111, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton_10.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1020, 420, 231, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton_11.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1280, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Чистый Холст"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начальный Рисунок"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пуск"))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузка"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Следующий"))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Создайте словарь из пар  "название функции": название функции. Так вы сможете легко вызвать функцию по её названию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша идея имеет право на жизнь.
Я не совсем понял чем должны отличаться методы "Пуск", "Чистый Холст", "Начальный Рисунок",
поэтому условно позиционирую на разные картинки.

Составьте свой список изображений.

Условное сохранение последнего рисунка по выходу из приложения.
Все, пробуйте.

PS: я не вижу как вы собираетесь сохранять раскрашенные рисунки, 
но это уже совсем другая история.

```
import sys
#import inspect
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets   #, uic


#import GlForm
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1280, 690)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1022, 20, 231, 28))
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 951, 621))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(255, 255, 255)")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1022, 60, 231, 28))
        self.pushButton_2.setText("")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1022, 110, 231, 28))
        self.pushButton_3.setText("")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1020, 150, 231, 28))
        self.pushButton_4.setText("")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1022, 190, 231, 28))
        self.pushButton_5.setText("")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1022, 230, 231, 28))
        self.pushButton_6.setText("")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1020, 330, 231, 28))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1020, 370, 231, 28))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 220, 111, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(482, 220, 111, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton_10.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1020, 420, 231, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton_11.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1280, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пуск"))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузка"))

        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Чистый Холст"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начальный Рисунок"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Следующий"))


#class PrApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, GlForm.Ui_MainWindow):
class PrApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, images):
        super().__init__()
# ++
        self.images    = images
        self.lenImages = len(self.images)
        self.indImg    = 0
        self.dataCsv   = ""

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;" % '#FF0000')
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;" % '#FFFFFF')
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;" % '#000000')
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;" % '#008000')
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;" % '#FF69B4')
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;" % '#4169E1')
        self.label.hide()
        self.last_x, self.last_y = None, None
        self.pen_color = QtGui.QColor('#FFFFFF')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_pen_color('#FF0000'))
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_pen_color('#FFFFFF'))
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_pen_color('#000000'))
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_pen_color('#008000'))
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_pen_color('#FF69B4'))
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_pen_color('#4169E1'))
        self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.pushButton_10.clicked.connect(self.load)
# ++
        self.pushButton_7.setEnabled(False) 
        self.pushButton_8.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton_11.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.chistxolst)              # Чистый Холст
        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.chistris1)               # Начальный Рисунок
        self.pushButton_11.clicked.connect(self.var2)                   # Следующий

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.last_x is None:
            self.last_x = e.x()
            self.last_y = e.y()
            return
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.label.pixmap())
        p = painter.pen()
        p.setWidth(8)
        p.setColor(self.pen_color)
        painter.setPen(p)
        painter.drawLine(self.last_x, self.last_y, e.x(), e.y())
        painter.end()
        self.update()
        self.last_x = e.x()
        self.last_y = e.y()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.last_x = None
        self.last_y = None

    def set_pen_color(self, c):
        self.pen_color = QtGui.QColor(c)

    def start(self):                                                    # "Пуск"
        self.indImg = 0
        self.dataCsv = "{},{:d}".format("start", self.indImg)   
        self.showLabel()
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(self.images[self.indImg]))

    def var2(self):                                                     # Следующий
        if self.indImg > self.lenImages - 2: self.indImg = 0
        else: self.indImg += 1    
        self.dataCsv = "{},{:d}".format("var2", self.indImg)
        self.showLabel()
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(self.images[self.indImg]))

    def chistxolst(self):                                               # Чистый Холст 
        self.indImg = 1
        self.showLabel()
        self.dataCsv = "{},{:d}".format("chistxolst", self.indImg)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(self.images[self.indImg]))

    def chistris1(self):                                                # Начальный Рисунок 
        self.indImg = 2
        self.showLabel()    
        self.dataCsv = "{},{:d}".format("chistris1", self.indImg)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(self.images[self.indImg]))


    def load(self):                                                    # Читаь файл и запустить функцию
        with open("data.csv", "r") as f:      
            metod, index = f.read().split(",")

        if metod == "start":
            self.start()                        
        elif metod == "chistris1":
            self.chistris1()
        elif metod == "chistxolst":
            self.chistxolst()            
        else:
            self.indImg = int(index)-1         
            self.var2()

    def showLabel(self): # То что повторяется больше одного раза, выносим в отдельный метод
        self.label.show()
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 951, 621))
        self.pushButton_9.hide()
        self.pushButton_10.hide()    
        self.pushButton_7.setEnabled(True) 
        self.pushButton_8.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton_11.setEnabled(True) 

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """ Выход из приложения и сохранение индекса последнего рисунка """

        reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, "Выход",
                                     "Вы уверены, что хотите выйти?",
                                     QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes, QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            with open('data.csv', 'w') as g:
                print(self.dataCsv, file=g)  
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()  


# Создайте список своих изибражений
images = [ 
    "image.png",
    "D:/_Qt/__Qt/img/max2.png",
    "D:/_Qt/__Qt/img/heart.png",
    "im.png",
    "Qt.png",
    # ...
]        

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PrApp(images)                     # + images
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]